# Entity Framework Query many levels with multiple results

Tags: sql, entity-framework, kendo-grid

```
select * from auto
where ( id in (
        select id from devis
        where ( devis.auto in (
               SELECT [id]     
               FROM statut
               where( par is null )
               ))
      ))
```

I have the following SQL query, I want to shape it using EF6 but I can't get it right, any help plz :)

Comment: What do you mean "right"?

Comment: I have tried this 

var auto = (from a in db.Autoes
orderby a.id                            
join s in db.statuts on null equals s.par
join d in db.devis on s.devis equals d.auto
select new {
id = a.id, nom = a.nom, prenom = a.prenom, telephone = a.telephone,
dateNaissance = a.dateNaissance, adresse = a.adresse, 
codePostal = a.codePostal, ville = a.ville, datePermis = a.datePermis});

but it gives me duplicate rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to achieve a double join, which could be expressed like this in LINQ:

```
from a in auto
join d in devis on a.id equals d.id
join s in statut on d.id equals s.id 
where s.par == null
select a
```

Comment: thank you :D I needed to change the where simply i put where a.id == d.id. ( what a shame o:) )